# Applescript: change in Monterey broke my script, can't figure out how to fix it

Tags: applescript, monterey

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell its application process "ControlCenter"
        tell its menu bar 1
            click its menu bar item "User"
        end tell
        
        tell its window "Control Center"
            tell its group 1
                set btns to its buttons
                repeat with btn in btns
                    if name of btn = "BrilliantCorners" then
                        click btn
                    end if
                end repeat
            end tell
        end tell
```

I'm getting the error

```
Can’t get group 1 of window \"Control Center\" of application process \"ControlCenter\". Invalid index
```

For some reason "group 1" no longer seems to be a valid index, and I don't know how to figure out what the new index would be. I'm new to scripting and trying to learn, so any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In **macOS Monterey**, using the **AppleScript** *code* in your question, I was able to get it to work by removing the `tell its group 1` *statement* and its closing `end tell` *statement*, e.g.:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell its application process "ControlCenter"
        tell its menu bar 1
            click its menu bar item "User"
        end tell
        
        tell its window "Control Center"
                set btns to its buttons
                repeat with btn in btns
                    if name of btn = "BrilliantCorners" then
                        click btn
                    end if
                end repeat
        end tell
```

**Notes:**

The **AppleScript** *code* shown here in is just a *snippet* and does not show the closing `end tell` *statement* for the working *code*.

Comment: Without that I still get exactly the same error on Monterey.